# Fetch data from server and show in PDF format

Tags: android, pdf

I am developing an app in which i am saving some data in book format.
I need to show data in same format or `pdf` format in mobile. i have read about `itextpdf`  but its too costly for me to use as  commercial use..

is there any other way to show data in `book format` in android app or in `pdf format`

Answer (score 1):

use iText java jar to make own pdf or use android native api PdfDocument PLease go through the link give below

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.html

Comment: i have more than 2000 pages in book.. is that right to create in memory card ... ??

Comment: i want to show server data within application in pdf or other book format .. is it possible ..?